# Templated Functions Depending on Container

Tags: c++, templates

I have a function where 'T' can either be a queue or a stack.
Currently for the function signature I have:

```
template <class T>
void foo(T<string> baa){

  //do something
}
```

Within foo I want to call T.pop() but I cannot do so.

I then wrote two version of pop, one for a queue and one for a stack.

```
string bar(stack<string> & baa){
  string t=baa.top();
  baa.pop();
  return t;
}
string bar(queue<string> & baa){
  string t=baa.front();
  baa.pop();
  return t;
}
```

I then tried to do this but it wouldn't work. How am I supposed to do this?

```
template <class T>
void foo(T<string> baa){
  //do something
  string baz=bar(baa);
}
```

EDIT:I forgot that top() simply removes the top element. I have now edited the code fragment to reflect those changes. However it still isn't working.

Comment: Those are not classes, but template classes.

Comment: Why enforcing `T<string>`? Wouldn't `T` be sufficient?

Comment: Have you checked the manual for what `pop()` does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do something like this, then *syntactically* what you need is **template template parameters**:

```
template<template<typename> class T>
void foo(T<string>& baa)
{
    ...
}
```

However, be aware that *the template parameters of the template template parameter `T` must match exactly the ones of the template template argument*, even though those parameters have default argument values.

In other words, since STL's `stack` and `queue` container adapters accept *two* type parameters (even though the second one has a default argument value), if you want them to be deduced as the template template arguments of your function template `foo()`, the template template parameter `T` must take *two* type parameters:

```
template<template<typename, typename> class T, typename C>
void foo(T<string, C>& baa)
{
    ...
}
```

I shall point out, though, that your current needs **do not seem to require such a design**. This is enough:

```
template<typename T>
string bar(T& baa)
{
    string t = baa.front();
    baa.pop();
    return t;
}
```

You would be forced to adopt the solution with template template parameters only if you had other function template *overloads* of `bar()` that need to work on non-container types, but again this does not seem to be your case.

Comment: Thanks, it seemed to have worked after I didn't force 'foo' to be of type T<string>.